# Angular Material Table not rendering columns

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I've been racking my brain over this and comparing to already working implementations I have done, but for some reason, my `<mat-table>` is not rendering the columns or the headers.

I have implemented it a few times in this project already so I know I have the correct imports and everything needed in order for it to work.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="indexBlock">
    <div id="inputs">
        <mat-form-field id="filterFormField">
            <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div id="tableDiv">
        <mat-table #matTable [dataSource]="unconfDataSource">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Supplier">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Supplier</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.Supplier}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="ContainerNo">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Container No</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.ContainerNo}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="InvoiceNum">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Invoice Num</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.InvoiceNum}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="VesselName">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Vessel Name</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.VesselName}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let myRowData; columns: displayedColumns" (click)="SelectImport(myRowData)"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ive stripped it down to only a few columns and removed my sorting and paginator in order to try and get it working.

My Controller is:

```
export class UnconfirmedComponent implements OnInit {
    unconfDataSource: MatTableDataSource<ImportHead>;
    displayedColumns: [
        'Supplier',
        'ContainerNo',
        'InvoiceNum',
        'VesselName'
    ];

    constructor(private _importService: ImportService,
                private _router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.GetImports();
    }

    GetImports() {
        this._importService.GetUnconfirmedImports()
                           .subscribe(imports => {
                               this.unconfDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ImportHead>(imports);
                           });
    }

    applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        filterValue = filterValue.trim();
        filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
        this.unconfDataSource.filter = filterValue;
    }

    SelectImport(event) {
        this._router.navigate(['/detail/' + event.Id]);
    }
}
```

I know that `myRowData` in the `<mat-row>` contains the correct data as when I click a row, it navigates correctly using that data.

However, this is the result:

[image]

It displays the correct number of rows, just no headers or actual data. When I inspect the table using F12 Developer Tools, the  elements are empty.

Therefore I assume theres an issue binding to maybe the `displayedColumns` property but I cannot find the issue. Also there are no errors in the Console.

TIA

Comment: And you are sure the service returns your data in the correct shape?

Comment: Yes it returns exactly the same data structure as my other implementations and they all use the same data model

Comment: Check out my answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change

```
displayedColumns: [
    'Supplier',
    'ContainerNo',
    'InvoiceNum',
    'VesselName'
];
```

to

```
displayedColumns =  [
    'Supplier',
    'ContainerNo',
    'InvoiceNum',
    'VesselName'
];
```

Comment: Yep that was it. Thankyou. I knew it would be something stupid like that but ive looked at it for so long I couldnt see it lol. Thankyou :)

Comment: It happens a lot. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Just need sanity checks sometimes and my partner in crime is on annual leave

Comment: Ahhhh!!!!!  I've spent 4 *hours* trying to figure this out, and all because of an assignment operator.  The horrors missing type checks, even within typescript, reveal their ugly heads again.  Can't wait to see C# running in the browser.  Thank you!